# Samsung galaxy note 2 android 4.3 problems

Tags: battery-life, 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-note-2

Is there a solution for the battery drain problem that the note 2 suffers after the 4.3 update? 
In my case the drain is most noticeable when the wifi is on. When its off battery lasts a good while same or maybe a little bit better than before. But when wifi is enabled, you can watch the battery indicator change values quickly. 
I've looked for solutions but found non that seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

There may be apps in the background that run which drains the battery life. To be certain of which app:
Go to

> Settings > Battery > Battery Graph

The battery graph will give detailed analysis which app used how much battery. If there is any app that you don't recall using a lot but is one of the top battery consumers I'd recommend you to uninstall/disable the said app.

Comment: I already did that the thing is, it is not apps that cause this drain, it is the wifi which when disabled everything is fine but when it is on i can watch the battery go down. Another thing is the SNS service it consumes alot. And what is the difference between Android system and android os. Both appear in the graph and both consume the most